# number of iterations formula?

Tags: algorithm, logic, equation

I have to create an equation in terms of n to find how many times the if ( sj < sindex) loop iterates. I can figure out how many times the loop iterates if I already have the value of n by running through the program manually(example if n = 4 the loop will iterate 6 times), but how would I go about making a generalized equation in terms of n?

```
         for i = 1 to n-1 {
         //find smallest in s1, ...., sn
         index = i 
         for j = i + 1 to n
             if ( sj < sindex)
                 index = j
             swap( si, sindex)
         }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inner loop runs from `i+1` to `n`, i.e. `n-i` times. The outer loop invokes it for `i=1, 2, ... n-1`, i.e. in total `n-1 + n-2 + ... n-(n-1)` times.

You need to express the sum of integers from `n-1` down to `1`. This sum has `n-1` terms.

Wen `n-1` is even, you can split the sum in two halves of `(n-1)/2` terms each: from `n-1` down to `(n+1)/2` and from `(n-1)/2` down to `1`. Reverse the second part and add pairwise, you will obtain: (n-1 + 1) + (n-2 + 2) + ... ((n+1)/2 + (n-1)/2).

All the pairs sum to `n`, and there are `(n-1)/2` of them, for a total of `n.(n-1)/2`.

Example with `n = 9`:

```
8 + 7 + 6 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1
=
8 + 7 + 6 + 5 +
1 + 2 + 3 + 4
=
9 + 9 + 9 + 9
```

Now if `n-1` is odd, `n-2` is even. You get the answer by adding `n-1` to the sum of the `n-2` first integers, i.e. `n-1 + (n-1).(n-2)/2 = n.(n-1)/2`.

In both cases, `n.(n-1)/2`.

Check: `4.(4-1)/2 = 6`.